# Converting Zend_Form_Element_Text to Zend_Form_Element_Hidden

Tags: php, zend-framework

In my controller script I have the following:

```
$customer_el = $this->view->form->getElement('customer_id');
Zend_Debug::dump($customer_el);
```

The output of it is

```
object(Zend_Form_Element_Text)#13 (26) {
  ["helper"] => string(8) "formText"
  ["_allowEmpty":protected] => bool(true)
  ["_autoInsertNotEmptyValidator":protected] => bool(true)
  ["_belongsTo":pro
... and so on.....
```

Is it possible to convert the $customer_el variable to Zend_Form_Element_Hidden ??
If so, how?

Comment: Is the main purpose is to hide the form element, then simply use change that element decorators.
`$element->setDecorators(array(array('ViewScript', array('viewScript' => 'path-to-hidden-partial.phtml'))));`

Comment: +1 for a good answer. But what I actually did was this: unset($this->_config->model->_form->customer_id);

Comment: Why do you use unset? Is that to remove the form element?

Comment: @php-dev In this case it will remove it.